# view my lowercase shell variables from a bash function using awk

Tags: bash, awk, variable

#### Outcome

Filter output the variables displayed using `set` or `declare` to show only **lowercase named shell** variables which is the convention I use for setting shell variables while testing.

##### Example

I set these:

```bash
$ declare -A pid=()
$ a=DHCP
$ something=test
```

I want the output to look like this:

```bash
$ lvar
a=DHCP
pids=()
something=test
```

I came up with this awk command for the `lvar` function:

```bash
declare | awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /^[a-z]+$/'
```

This works perfectly when run from the command line. However, as a function sourced in and run, I get an error which I think is caused by **awk's field parameter** `$1` being interpreted as a **bash function parameter**.

```bash
$ vi func
function lvar() {
  declare |awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /^[a-z]+$/'
}
```

Running **lvar** gives this error:

```bash
$ lvar
awk: cmd. line:1:  ~ /^[a-z]+$/
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```bash
$ declare -p -f lvar
lvar () 
{ 
    declare | awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /^[a-z]+$/'
}
```

### Update 1

My original approach with an **awk command defined as a `bash` function**, does actually work - only on my Linux box and not on my Mac where I originally defined it.

I'll have to figure out the **macOS issue** and post an update to you all here in due course.
Many thanks for your time :)

### Update 2

Okay, I checked if the `bash shopt` options on my Linux vs macOS were different but that wasn't it.

I opened iTerm on Mac and the function behaves as expected but shows no output in Terminal.app.

Very odd that its specific to some setting in Terminal.app. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure that the code you run uses single quotes rather than double quotes around the `awk` code? Check with `declare -p -f lvar`.  Also note that `$1` in `awk` is not a positional parameter, but the value of the first field of the current record.

Comment: You present an `awk` syntax error, `$1` is not "interpreted as a bash variable". You have to present a reproducible example. Your `awk` command is valid but has no argument and just waiting for stdin.

Comment: @thanasisp I forgot the `declare |` part. Updated.

Comment: Still I don't see how can I reproduce the error.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I'm definitely using single quotes `('')`. RE: Awk's `$1` - Ah, yes, **field** is the name that was eluding me. Updated.

Comment: You 'd get this error exactly if you use double quotes for the awk body. Your current description is not reproducible.

Comment: @thanasisp Are you sure you've added the `declare |` part to the function?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the current updated description.

Comment: You are both right! I just tested on my Linux box and it DOES work. Does NOT seem to work on my Mac. Strange, both are running Bash 5 although slightly different versions.

Comment: I can't help but notice the two spaces between `:` and `~` in the error message. I wouldn't be surprised if there was some hidden character there. Or maybe a whitespace character other than space or tab such as the non-breaking space.

Comment: Regarding `lowercase named shell variables which is the convention I use for setting shell variables while testing` - that suggests you don't use lowercase variable names in your production code which would be a bad thing. Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: Regarding your function definitions like `function lvar() { foo }` - get rid of the nonportable, redundant `function` keyword and just do `lvar() { foo }`.

Comment: Note that `bash` has two sets of options, one managed with `shopt`, one managed with `set`. See the output of `set +o` for the latter. In any case, the difference here seems to be about awk, not bash.

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`, you can get the list of variable names (though not the ones that have been declared but not assigned) into an array with:

```
readarray -t Vars < <(compgen -v)
```

You can filter that with `grep`:

```
readarray -t Vars < <(compgen -v | grep -x '[[:lower:]]*') &&
  [ "${#Vars[@]}" -gt 0 ] &&
  declare -p -- "${Vars[@]}"
```

For the all-lowercase ones for instance.

Change the `grep` filter to `grep -v '[[:upper:]]'` for all variables except those whose name contains an uppercase letter, or `grep '[[:lower:]]' | grep -v '[[:upper:]]'` for those with at least one lowercase letter and no upper.

In any case, you can't post-process the output of `declare` line-by-line like you're trying to do as variable values may very well be made of several lines, and at least when the `posix` option is enabled, `bash` will display them (the scalar ones at least) like:

```
var='line 1
line 2'
```

With the `posix` option disabled, it seems that `bash` 5.1 at least always renders the newline character as `$'\n'` which would guarantee that each variable definition is on a single line.

In that case, you could do:

```
(set +o posix; declare | grep -E '^[[:lower:]]+=')
```

To list the definition of variables whose name is all-lowercase (assuming the variable values are short enough or that your `grep` doesn't choke on lines larger than `LINE_MAX` bytes).

Like for `compgen -v`, that doesn't include declared unassigned variables.

Comment: While this is a novel way to get all environment variables into an array, the solution needs to be a single command which is why I've put this into a function. Btw, my approach seems to work, but not on my Mac for some reason.

Comment: @TonyBarganski, feel free to put that code in a function.

Comment: I tested the above code but it doesn't do what I'm after, which is that: every var {name} is in lowercase, regardless of the letter case of the var's values.

Comment: @TonyBarganski, don't know what you mean. `compgen -v | grep -x '[[:lower:]]*'` lists the variable **names** that are made entirely of lower case characters.

Comment: If `compgen -v | grep -x '[[:lower:]]*'` shows any uppercase character, there's something definitely broken with your macOS installation. To get the values, you'd pass the list of variables (retrieved by `readarray` for instance) to `declare -p` as my code show.

Comment: `compgen -v | grep -x '[[:lower:]]*'` in my bash shell lists both upper and lowercase vars but with not values. Note also that my awk command does work as expected, printing lowercase 'named' vars with their values. It seems for some reason, it doesn't work in mac Terminal.app. Fine in iTerm.app and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
typeset -m '[[:lower:]]#'
```

Would print the definition of variables whose name is made entirely of lowercase letters.

```
set -o extendedglob
typeset -m '^*[[:upper:]]*'
```

For those that don't contain uppercase letters, to also include `foo_bar` or `var1` for instance or

```
set -o extendedglob
typeset -m '*[[:lower:]]*~*[[:upper:]]*'
```

For those that contain at least one lowercase letter, and no upper case ones, to exclude variables named like `__` or `_123_` or those with *letters* that don't have a lowercase nor uppercase form compared to the previous one.

Beware `zsh` completion defines a lot of such variables.

Comment: Appreciate this may well be accurate but the question is specifically for `bash`.

Comment: @TonyBarganski, yes, I gave an answer for `bash` as well, this answer will come handy for anybody coming here with the same question for `zsh` (or when you decide to switch to `zsh` eventually ;-)).

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that its my fault, I didn't specifically specify `bash function` in my original post. I tried to undo my down vote but it won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my function method stands. There was some **crazy Terminal.app issue** which had nothing to do with the function.

From:

```bash
$ vi ~/.bash_functions
lvar() {
  declare |awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /^[a-z]+$/'
}
```

To:

```bash
$ vi ~/.bash_functions
function lvar() {
  declare |awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /^[a-z]+$/'
}
```

I really wish I could point a finger as to what the problem was but it started working in **Terminal.app** after I gave the long function definition format using **function** keyword, in my main bash functions file, closed Terminal.app and reopened it. Hey presto - it worked! Then removed the 'function' keyword in my main bash functions and it kept on working. - Scratching my head. Apologies if this wasted anyone's time.

Comment: The only time you need to use the `function` keyword is if you have the same name defined as an alias that you want to use for the function. Don't do that as it'll get confusing (but I really don't think that was related to whatever your problem was).